# How to catch event while unit testing?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, nunit

Hi I have a problem testing an event using `NUnit`. I'm not even sure if this should be unit or functional test. Let me show you the sample class first (I'm trying to test `OnValueInjected` event):

```
public class Foo
{
    private IBar CurrentBar { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<MoveEventArgs> OnValueInjected;

    public Foo()
    {
        StartFoo();
    }    

    private async void StartFoo()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (State != FooState.Finished)
            {
                IResult result = CurrentBar.WaitForValue(); // This is blocking function, wait for a value

                OnValueInjected?.Invoke(this, new ResultEventArgs(result));

                // .. rest of the loop
            }
        });
    }

    public void InjectValue(int a, int b)
    {
        CurrentBar.Inject(a,b);
    }
}
```

So, basically what I'm trying to do is to subscribe to the event, call `InjectValue` and check if the event was called. Like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void FooOnValueInjectedTest()
    {
        bool OnValueInjectedWasRasied = false;

        IFoo foo = new Foo();
        foo.OnValueInjected += (s, e) => OnValueInjectedWasRasied = true;

        foo.InjectValue(0,0);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, OnValueInjectedWasRasied);
    }
```

Pretty straightforward, BUT it looks like `InjectValue` is too slow. The test is failing..I think it's too slow, because when I add `Thread.Sleep` between `InjectValue` and `Assert` to works.

```
        foo.InjectValue(0,0);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, OnValueInjectedWasRasied);
```

Is there a better way to test such an event? Thanks

I fixed my class, so it's like that now:

```
public class Foo
{
    private AutoResetEvent AutoReset { get; }

    private IBar CurrentBar { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<MoveEventArgs> OnValueInjected;

    public Foo()
    {
        AutoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        StartFoo();
    }

    private async void StartFoo()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (State != FooState.Finished)
            {
                IResult result = CurrentBar.WaitForValue(); // This is blocking function, wait for a value

                OnValueInjected?.Invoke(this, new ResultEventArgs(result));

                AutoReset.Set();

                // .. rest of the loop
            }
        });
    }

    public void InjectValue(int a, int b)
    {
        if (CurrentBar.Inject(a,b))
        {
            AutoReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, do you *want* your `InjectValue` to return before the event handlers have definitely been raised? You're basically seeing the natural result of asynchrony... it's not really about events, but about asynchronous execution.

Comment: @JonSkeet hmm.. technically, Are you saying that `InjectValue` could be blocked until `OnValueInjected` was raised? I haven't thought about that actually..

Comment: If you *wanted* that behavior, you could ensure it, yes. Whether you do or not is a different matter though.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks! I actually want that behavior. I edited my question with updated code. Can you check if this is what you meant? The test passes, but I just wanted to be sure we're on the same page, thx!

Comment: That's one potential solution, but you may need to consider the situation where multiple threads call `InjectValue` at the same time. It's going to be pretty tricky if you want to make sure one call to `InjectValue` only completes when *that* value has triggered all the event handlers. Oh, and it's also going to deadlock if the event handler calls `InjectValue` itself. Sorry for pointing out these problems - threading is inherently hard :(

Comment: @JonSkeet not a problem, any problem spotted is a gold! I was looking for potential deadlocks tbh. But, `WaitForValue` function is blocked by `BlockingCollection` with capacity of "1". `InjectValue ` is basically `TryAdd` on this blocking collection. So..With that being said - you can add value ONLY if the collection is empty and `WaitForValue` function is waiting.. If you call `InjectValue` many times - second call and the rest will be ignored.

Comment: The only thing missing, is to make sure that loop is currently running, when someone calls `InjectValue`. I will need to check the status probably

Comment: Oh, and I was thinking about adding a timeout to the waitOne - just in case.

Comment: I've seen this issue in the past. As Jon had mentioned, it is a problem with asynchronous calling.

A quick solution would be to make the InjectValue method awaitable and do a .Wait on the ACT of the test method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a problem of asynchronous calling. Whenever you have an async method in an NUnit test, it doesn't wait for it to be done as no one is actually waiting for it to be done and return the result. Instead, you have to do a .Wait on the async method to force the test to wait for it to be done.

I did not write this code in a code editor so it may not be perfect but that's the basic idea.

```
public class Foo
{
    private AutoResetEvent AutoReset { get; }

    private IBar CurrentBar { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<MoveEventArgs> OnValueInjected;

    public Foo()
    {
        AutoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        StartFoo();
    }

    private async void StartFoo()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (State != FooState.Finished)
            {
                IResult result = CurrentBar.WaitForValue(); // This is blocking function, wait for a value

                OnValueInjected?.Invoke(this, new ResultEventArgs(result));

                AutoReset.Set();

                // .. rest of the loop
            }
        });
    }

    public async void InjectValue(int a, int b)
    {
        if (CurrentBar.Inject(a,b))
        {
            AutoReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your test method in the ACT you do a .Wait

```
[Test]
public void FooOnValueInjectedTest()
{
    // Arrange
    bool OnValueInjectedWasRasied = false;

    IFoo foo = new Foo();
    foo.OnValueInjected += (s, e) => OnValueInjectedWasRasied = true;

    // Act
    foo.InjectValue(0,0).Wait();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(true, OnValueInjectedWasRasied);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, but `foo.InjectValue(0,0);` function is not awaitable. Doesn't have to be. It should inject a value into blocking collection. After collection is filled, it's released. It's a very real scenario - so I was wondering how to test it (without changing the code ofc). Should I test it?

Comment: I must have misunderstood the method and thought that the Inject method is calling another async method within it. My bad.

As for should you test it? That depends on the answer to the question "What are you trying to test?" It doesn't seem like there is much to be tested there.